# Como insertar SQL con datos de una Consulta?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

necesito insertar datos en una tabla en otra tabla. Basicamente requiero hacer esto:

```
INSERT INTO Consulta (tipo, busqueda1, resultado1, resultado2, resultado3)
```

El valor del campo `tipo` lo defino yo, pero los valores de los otros campos se extraen de la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT CODIGO_USUARIO, Electrodomestico, Cant FROM (SELECT CODIGO_USUARIO, [Abanico Mesa], [Abanico Techo], [Estufa Elect 1F] FROM TempCensoElect) p UNPIVOT (Cant FOR Electrodomestico IN ([Abanico Mesa], [Abanico Techo], [Estufa Elect 1F])) AS unpvt
```

Dando como resultado lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos de la columna `CODIGO_USUARIO` deben insertarse en los campos `busqueda1, resultado1`. Los datos de la columna `Electrodomestico` debe insertarse en el campo `resultado2` y los datos de la columna `Cant` deben insertarse en el campo `resultado3`

¿Como puedo hacer esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La consulta quedaría algo parecido a esto:

```
INSERT INTO Consulta

SELECT 'Condicion para tipo' as Tipo,CODIGO_USUARIO as busqueda1,CODIGO_USUARIO as resultado1,
       Electrodomestico as resultado2, Cant as resultado3
FROM 
        (SELECT CODIGO_USUARIO, [Abanico Mesa], [Abanico Techo], [Estufa Elect 1F] 
        FROM TempCensoElect) p UNPIVOT (Cant FOR Electrodomestico IN ([Abanico Mesa], 
        [Abanico Techo], [Estufa Elect 1F])) AS unpvt
```

Comment: no les des el pescado, enséñales a pescar !

Answer (score 2):

Los valores regresados de tu *select* deben tener el mismo orden y cantidad de columnas insertados en tu *insert*.

Veo 1 problema en tu lógica:

Estas insertando tipo, pero no tienes ningun valor para insertar tipo en tu select, si no vas a extraerlo entonces quitalo de tu insert o agrega algun valor a tu consulta

Fuera de eso solo necesitas agregar un alias para el campo codigo_usuario para poder ser insertado en dos campos

```
select codigo_usuario as cu1, Codigo_usuario as cu2, electrodomestico,cant...
```

Referencia :

> https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: Recomiendo que no usemos w3schools como referencia y acudamos a fuentes más fiables (relevantes). [w3fools](https://web.archive.org/web/20130302014219/http://w3fools.com/)